# Segfault when creating a tcp::acceptor

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a simple program that has just begun to segfault. The `main()` function looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::string peerRequestPort;
        std::cout << "enter port listening: ";
        std::cin >> peerRequestPort;

        asio::io_service io_service;

        network::PeerManager peerManager(network::Peer({"0,0,0,0",peerRequestPort}));

        network::PeerRequestServer peerRequestServer(io_service,peerRequestPort);
        peerRequestServer.Start(peerManager);
```

I'm getting the segfault on the creation of an `asio::ip::tcp::acceptor` in the `PeerRequestServer` constructor. The constructor for the `PeerManager` doesn't do any data manipulation or anything, it just stores the provided `Peer` struct. The `PeerRequestServer` constructor also doesn't do anything, it just initiates an `asio::ip::tcp::acceptor` with the provided `asio::io_service&`.

The call stack is

```
#0 0041C77D asio::detail::service_registry::keys_match(key1=..., key2=...) 
#1 ??   0x0041cbd2 in asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service (this=0xa631a0, key=..., factory=0x41cef8 <asio::detail::service_registry::create<asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::ip::tcp> >(asio::io_service&)>) 
#2 0041CA6A asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::ip::tcp> >(this=0xa631a0) 
#3 004116CB asio::use_service<asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::ip::tcp> >(ios=...) 
#4 00412A2B asio::basic_io_object<asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::ip::tcp>, true>::basic_io_object(this=0x28fcec, io_service=...)
#5 00413079 asio::basic_socket_acceptor<asio::ip::tcp, asio::socket_acceptor_service<asio::ip::tcp> >::basic_socket_acceptor(this=0x28fcec, io_service=..., endpoint=..., reuse_addr=true) 
#6 00409513 network::PeerRequestServer::PeerRequestServer(this=0x28fcec, ioService=..., portListen=...) 
#7 00401B24 _fu38___ZSt3cin()
```

Here is `PeerRequestServer`s constructor:

```
PeerRequestServer::PeerRequestServer(asio::io_service& ioService, std::string portListen)
: m_acceptor(ioService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(),std::stoi(portListen)))
{
    std::clog << __func__ << std::endl;
}
```

And the `PeerManager`s:

```
PeerManager::PeerManager(Peer self)
: m_self(self)
{
}
```

So I can't see where from the start of main, into the `PeerRequestServer` constructor, there's a possibility of me causing the segfault...

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the IP be `0.0.0.0` not `0,0,0,0`?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something else wrong that you're not showing.

Of course the spelling `0,0,0,0` is questionable. But the code you show works just fine:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fefdea34edcfb33)</kbd>**

> #### This is why you should create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) or https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

namespace network {
    struct Peer {
        Peer(tcp::resolver::query) {}
    };

    struct PeerManager {
        PeerManager(Peer self) : m_self(self) {}
        Peer m_self;
    };

    struct PeerRequestServer {
        PeerRequestServer(asio::io_service &ioService, std::string portListen)
            : m_acceptor(ioService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), std::stoi(portListen))) {
                std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
            }

        void Start(PeerManager&) {
            // TODO 
        }

        tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
    };
}

int
main() {
    try {
        std::string peerRequestPort;
        std::cout << "enter port listening: ";
        std::cin >> peerRequestPort;

        asio::io_service io_service;

        network::PeerManager peerManager(network::Peer({ "0,0,0,0", peerRequestPort }));

        network::PeerRequestServer peerRequestServer(io_service, peerRequestPort);
        peerRequestServer.Start(peerManager);
    } catch (std::exception const &e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: See also **[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**.